# IBM MobileFirst Push Notification Not Received in Android Platform

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

We are integrating the IBM MobileFirst based ionic v3 hybrid mobile application and integrating the push notification but the message not yet received in device. we did necessary setup in firewall as per IBM guide line as well as we referred google docs but the notification not at all working.

We did workaround for the mobile app device register the token manually added in CURL command and executed in same server machine box but the notification able to received or arrived in device.

We could not able to identified the issues root cause in IBM mobile server side. please some one help us.

Note : we did not used ibm mfp based app token, we just used normal ionic app with fcm sdk added project to generated fcm google device token and its working fine in CURL.

we follow up below link to setup the firewall settings but the android notification not working. please help us.

our fix pack details : Product version: 8.0.0.00-20200121-1306

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#firebase-cloud-messaging

The CURL Test Command the notification received .

```
curl -k -X POST --header "Authorization: key=AAAAQoVeXz0:AA91bFA794sGrVc5ha1x0xoloCr14S4Z7U5T-ROP3zVaAoZutMRtYeu-zMBB7u4vN5yLG5eHDctCdsBP_x3WdSPV0TDmA4_zk40UShab1D-WlwQdslP0kBQZrHzuHPSWgANFF8Kft"  --Header "Content-Type: application/json"  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send  -d "{\"to\":\" cyhV_ewwGM:APA91bE_hl3fpZxnz6ZU40xCX4_81r6rvDnimiNIhVfFTJoBwXHBJaOY9JEjJZ_9KZpB_itzCFV0Nhvg06iuawFMUb17Ifpb4xs7yZpd0PxoV6GyRI2b5XjLHKnhdm2R3GevcX9bn\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Testing CommandLine\"}"}
```

Comment: How are you sending the notifications - via the MF console or via a REST API call ? Please update this question with what you see in the server logs when you send the notification

Comment: Is  MFP server allowed to connect to the internet directly? If not, is MFP server connecting to a proxy that is open to the internet?

Comment: Srik - the logs we can't able to see any error or success message . we tried mfp console and rest API. the IOS working and android not working

Comment: vivin - this is standalone server and the box connected internal network. also they enabled internet on that particular box. yes the proxy open to internet.

Comment: if we create normal hybrid push app with generate device token to help of fcm plugin , the device token use in CURL command line for testing purpose, the notification has been received in android ..

Comment: but if we using MFP based ionic 3 hybrid app, the app once register the notification, we will get confirmation and token details, after that, if we use this device token in CURL the notification not at all working or received message .....